# "fatal: ambiguous argument 'v': unknown revision or path not in the working tree" in Git

Tags: git, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am building my binaries using [Gitian Builder](https://gitian.org/) for my own blockchain (template from Peershare) that is run on my localhost. When I execute  the command `git pull` for Gitian Builder, it gives a time-out error. I don't know why (I already the proxy working behind). When I execute the command

```
cd ~/gitian-builder
./bin/gbuild --commit abc=v${VERSION} ../abc/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-linux.yml
```

where "abc" is the blockchain name, it gives me an error like this:

```
 remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
 remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
 From https://bitbucket.org/abc/abc
    1eed3dd..8316d74  master     -> master
 fatal: ambiguous argument 'v': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
  Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
  'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
    ./bin/gbuild:272:in `block in <main>': error looking up commit for    tag v (RuntimeError)
    from ./bin/gbuild:256:in `each'
     from ./bin/gbuild:256:in `<main>'
```

where my *./bin/gbuild* file is from  *https://github.com/devrandom/gitian-builder/blob/master/bin/gbuild* and my *gitian-linux.yml* file looks like this:

```
 name: "abc"
 suites:
 - "precise"
 architectures:
 - "i386"
 - "amd64"
  packages:
  - "g++"
  - "git-core"
  - "unzip"
   - "pkg-config"
   - "faketime"
   - "zlib1g-dev"
   - "qt4-qmake"
   - "libqt4-dev"
   reference_datetime: "2011-01-30 00:00:00"
   remotes:
  - "url": "https://bitbucket.org/abc/abc.git"
      "dir": "abc"
      files:
          - "abc-deps-linux32-gitian-r5.zip"
          - "abc-deps-linux64-gitian-r5.zip"
          - "boost-linux32-1.55.0-gitian-r1.zip"
         - "boost-linux64-1.55.0-gitian-r1.zip"
        script: |
         STAGING="$HOME/install"
         OPTFLAGS='-O2'
         BINDIR="${OUTDIR}/bin/${GBUILD_BITS}" # 32/64 bit build specific output directory
        TEMPDIR="$HOME/tempdir"
        export TZ=UTC
        export LIBRARY_PATH="$STAGING/lib"
        export PATH="$STAGING/bin:$PATH"
        mkdir -p ${BINDIR}
                            .... and more
```

How can I solve the error and get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

Gitian only builds against valid Git tags. The bitcoin repository uses tags in the format

```
v0.13.1
```

Note the leading `v`. Since you did not share your repository, I can not tell you what the correct version string will be. But you can use the `git` command in your `abc` repository to list correct tag names, e.g.,

```
git tag

0.0.1
0.0.2
0.0.3
0.0.4
0.1.0
```

If like in the example case above, you tagged the version without the leading `v`, remove it from your Gitian Builder command, i.e.,

```
$ ./bin/gbuild --commit abc=${VERSION} ../abc/contrib/gitian-descriptors/gitian-linux.yml
```

If you do not have any tags in your `abc` repository yet, read more about [Git tags here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging).